# Listen to changing text in a span Element

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a `span` element which displays a changing duration value.

```
<span id="vtime">--:--</span>
```

Unfortunately, due to the JavaSscript API I am using these is no way to pick up that value other than to listen to the changing text in the `span` element.

I want to pick up the values and execute a JavaScript AJAX command to fetch a value for the captions at certain time instances such as 11:30, 23:30...

What's the best way of doing this?

Server Environment: PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i understand the question correctly you can use `setInterval()` to run a JavaScript function; lets say every 5 or 10 seconds ... it picks up the `value` from inside the span by maybe using `document.getElementById('vtime').textContent` and compare to the time you want to run a specific fetch command at.

Comment: that's what i have thinking... seems like that's the best way.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why not put it in the code that's actually updating `#vtime`?

Comment: Then your best bet is probably going to be listening to the contents of that value.